# replicate table 1 and combine a value from table2

Tags: sql

I have  table1 like this:

[image]

and other column in table2 having two unique value 3 and 4.
How do I write a query to make a table like

[image]

Actually My table is more complicated than the one above: 
I tried :

```
"Select DISTINCT table1.x, table1.y ,table2.z from table1 Where table1.a = "something' 
and table1.b is Not Null, 
CROSS JOIN table2 Where table2.z='something' OR table2.z='something2' "
```

it does not work...I am using a modeling package which use the sql language and I am not sure it is fully compatible with sql.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to find the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of two tables. It can be short as:

```
select * from table1, table2;
```

Or explicitly using a `cross join` as:

```
select table1.*, table2.*
from table1 cross join table2;
```

---

To filter each table individually, you can use sub-queries:

```
select distinct table1.x, table1.y, table2.z
from (select * from table1
  where table1.a = 'something' and table1.b is not NULL
) as table1
cross join (select * from table2
  where table2.z = 'something' or table2.z = 'something2'
) as table2;
```

Or use combine the logic under one query:

```
select distinct table1.x, table1.y, table2.z
from table1, table2
where table1.a = 'something' and table1.b is not NULL
    and (table2.z = 'something' or table2.z = 'something2')
```